# mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write: 'all of a sudden' plenty of room still...Drupal 6 installation

Tags: mysql

On the dev server, I tried to run the same script I've been using for almost a year and at the end got the : mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

Last week, the IT sysadmin just restored the virtual server to a few days before backup and it all worked.

The Drupal install is fine and the live server is fine (a duplicate of the dev server)...we have about 30 or so virtual servers all on the same box and the IT SysAdmin has allocated quite a few resources.

Here's what I get with df -h on the dev:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        18G  6.1G   12G  36% /
udev           1000M  4.0K 1000M   1% /dev
tmpfs           403M  228K  403M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           1007M     0 1007M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1       100G  8.1G   87G   9% /data
xxxx@dev1:~$
```

and the basic output after running my script in the command line:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 5416: Can't create table
>   'content_type_ses_job_postings' (errno: 28) mysqldump: Got errno 32 on
>   write ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '198.xx.xx.xx' (111) LDAP server IP updated.

Note that I get that last `ERROR 2003` about not connecting to the MySQL server even when it all works so though that shouldn't happen, I think that's more of the user problem as the databases backup, save, and then import to the 'holding' db which I then switch to when updating content so perhaps that's something, but it's never been a specific problem.

If `error 32` is related to space, where could the space problem be? If it's related to permissions, which folder would the permissions problem be on? However, I don't know how or what could have dynamically changed the permissions anywhere as...I stated before, I've been running these scripts for about 8 months with no problem?

The basics of the dev server

- MySQL 5.5.24
- Ubuntu0.12.04.1
- PHP 5.3

Comment: How big is the file you created with mysqldump, or are you piping mysqldump somewhere ???

Comment: Is `content_type_ses_job_postings` bigger now that it was 8 months ago ?

Comment: Is `content_type_ses_job_postings` a MyISAM table ???

Comment: yes, but it's empty and that particular field hasn't been changed. When trying again, it was a different field so it doesn't seem to be failing on a certain field/type of data, it's random. From phpMyAdmin on that field: 0  MyISAM  utf8_general_ci  1.0 KiB

Comment: ..for instance, I just got:
ERROR 1 (HY000) at line 1570: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/Robin/content_field_product_current_view.MYI' (Errcode: 28)
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

Comment: ..oh and as to your first comment, it's about 170 megs. Drupal db...the Dev server is completely separate from the live server..they are exactly the same as to specs but the mysql server is on the Dev only..so, dump from dev...import to 1 of 2 databases on live (whichever is not in use)... then I log into the live and copy the appropriate Batman.settings.php or Robin.settings.php file -whichever the dump was imported to--to settings.php and the site is updated. So live server has two databases, dev just one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seems strange

```
[root@*****]# perror 28
OS error code  28:  No space left on device
[root@*****]# perror 32
OS error code  32:  Broken pipe
```

Since the mysqldump keeps breaking at random places, it is space-related, and no disk full condition, I would suspect the problem at a deeper layer : the MySQL Packet. What is a MySQL Packet?

According to the [page 99 of the Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009577)

[image: BookImage]

here are paragraphs 1-3 explaining it:

> MySQL network communication code was
>   written under the assumption that
>   queries are always reasonably short,
>   and therefore can be sent to and
>   processed by the server in one chunk,
>   which is called a *packet* in MySQL
>   terminology. The server allocates the
>   memory for a temporary buffer to store
>   the packet, and it requests enough to
>   fit it entirely. This architecture
>   requires a precaution to avoid having
>   the server run out of memory---a cap
>   on the size of the packet, which this
>   option accomplishes.
>
> The code of interest in relation to
>   this option is found in
>   **sql/net_serv.cc**. Take a look at **my_net_read()**, then follow the call to **my_real_read()** and pay
>   particular attention to
>   **net_realloc()**.
>
> This variable also limits the length
>   of a result of many string functons.
>   See **sql/field.cc** and
>   **sql/intem_strfunc.cc** for details.

Given this explanation, making bulk INSERTs will load/unload a MySQL Packet rather quickly. This is especially true when max_allowed_packet is too small for the given load of data coming at it.

I wrote about this before : [MySQL server has gone away obstructing import of large dumps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5323/877)

Try raising [max_allowed_packet for the mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) to `1G` as follows:

```
mysqldump --max-allowed-packet=1073741824 ...
```

and try the mysqldump.

If this does not do it, then do this:

Added this to my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 1G
```

Then, login to MySQL as `root@localhost` and run this

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

and try the mysqldump.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Great info! Thanks so much. I logged into both the dev/live to mysql, called Status and both showed no databases in use??? But, after doing that, I refreshed my browser and everything is back to normal. I will check that variable.. I know in the php.ini file I have:
memory_limit: -1
post_max_size 500M
upload_max_filesize 450M
So I will now check that variable you mentioned, thanks again!