# mysqldump: Got errno 28 on write

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error even if I have plenty of space on my drives.

https://sittinginoblivion.com/wiki/backup-failed-mysqldump-got-errno-28-write says its disk space problem.

I am using PUTTY and this command to export database

```
mysqldump -h [HOST] --port=[PORT] -u [USERNAME]  -p [DBNAME] > E:\[FILENAME].sql
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write: 'all of a sudden' plenty of room still...Drupal 6 installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533323/mysqldump-got-errno-32-on-write-all-of-a-sudden-plenty-of-room-still-drupa)

Comment: @EmrahIzci Please read subject of the question

Comment: have you tried this? SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

Comment: Other user have same accss rights as me...They can export but i cant. Is there any issue with PUTTY? Or just use windows command prompt?

Comment: Thanks @EmrahIzci windows command prompt worked!

Answer (score 92):

**Error Message**

> Backup failed: mysqldump: Got errno 28 on write

**Meaning**

> Insufficient disk space to store output.

**Solution**

> Free up some disk space. You might want to track down the reason
>   you're low on disk space too.

**Source:** 
https://sittinginoblivion.com/wiki/backup-failed-mysqldump-got-errno-28-write

Comment: This is not a disk space issue.

Comment: @JulieC then what is the issue?

Comment: it was a disk space issue for me! We have a 50GB database, and the first dump failed due to a broken pipe ssh time out, and the second dump failed because i didn't delete the first dump and i got the: Got errno 28 on write

Comment: For me it just was a disk space problem too, in Windows. Forgot to look after free space for several months, happily creating backups each day which reduced space. So thank god we have meaningful error messages. Though it could be slightly more exact.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error but it turned out that there was no memory left to accommodate a new file. Removing unwanted files to free up the space for new (*.sql) file helped.

P.S: You can see your memory consumption by the command: df -h.

Comment: The question says: *I have plenty of space on my drives*.

Answer (score 3):

I came here with the same problem, plenty of space. Also putty.

I noticed than using the same command but in another folder with mod 777 (write everybody) the problem of space is gone and the command runs succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with putty.

Dont use putty, Just go to windows command prompt, Go to folder where mysql.exe, mysqldump.exe etc.. are there & just enter this command.

Remember never try to take dump from `MYSQL>` command prompt

C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -h [HOST] --port=[PORT] -u [USERNAME]  -p [DBNAME] > E:[FILENAME].sql

Enter password: ------

Worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

When I get this error, I check that mysql server use a very high virtual memory.
So I add more swap space to the server and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on an AWS EC2 instance (Cloud9 specifically) and it was caused by both insufficient hardware and insufficient disk space.

I used a higher class of EC2 instance and the `mysqldump: Got errno 28 on write` error was replaced by an error about insufficient disk space.